# HttpResponse, HttpRequest, WebClient

Tags: c#, webforms

Where should I begin as a best practice to simulate a web browser as most easiest way?

I have built up an regular user login, and a update-user-info (test project things) on a webform which I now wan't to simulate a fill-in, programmically. How do I keep the Sessions and put my own values into the specific input-forms, simulate click on buttons and links?

The steps of the project is
login (username / password)
find link to form (some random links/text)
fill in form (some inputs)
click save (which confirm to me by mail)

Comment: Isn't there a web browser control floating around somewhere?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "simulate a web browser"? Do you want javascript? Rendering? Or are you just looking for HTTP traffic?

Comment: Oded, javascripts are complicating things a lot. Which are already known (try browsing with linx), so no! Javascript are going behind this :-). Just simple post/get http traffic.

Comment: ChaosPandion. Your probably more close then it first looked like. I found this and will check it up after my trip to work. farooqazam.net/c-sharp-auto-click-button-and-auto-fill-form/

Comment: hmz.. why are so many using comments? I find it troublesome to Accept-mark some questions :). There should be a "create answer of this comment"-function

Comment: @ChaosPandion Please add your comment as an answer, because that's the closest to an answer we are, for this question! Very useful I will say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, sounds like you're looking for a web form test client.  If you're using VS2010 Premium or higher, you can use a Coded UI Test to simulate what you describe -- open up a browser, log in to a site, fill out a form, submit it (using data driven from an external source), and validate the results.

Take a look at Coded UI Tests [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286681.aspx) to see if this meets your needs.

Here's also a [video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/kmcgrath/Introduction-to-Creating-Coded-UI-Tests-with-Visual-Studio-2010) from Channel9 that's a decent walk-through intro of Coded UI Tests.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The most important sense here, is that the tasks should be done programmically, without user interaction. Selenium looks nice but I'm not out for third party software, this is a c# thread :)

Comment: You can code the UI tests or have someone record them.  VS2010 generates a C# class as a result of the recording, and you can manipulate it as you please.  It generates pure C#.  We use it on my team and it's working out pretty well.

Comment: I find that comment interesting. Will check it up from work tomorrow. I've tried being into the VS testprojects a few times but always fall back on a usefull purpose. That's to much to do just to get an answer "Success. Your query returned more then 5 row" I mean.. hey? :).

Comment: Oh, Premium and Pro are different versions. So OK No, I still need help with going further to coding this manually. Why did this question completely missed out answers for pure c# coding?

Comment: You didn't state that you wanted a pure C# solution.  And, technically, Coded UI tests do produce a pure C# result - it's just you have to have a license of VS2010 Premium or higher.  You didn't state what environment you were working in.  Sorry I couldn't be of help.

Comment: Thanks David. I gaved the question one tag, C#. Someone else edited in webforms. If I use SharpDevelope, Vs Ultimate, Net 4/2 or Notepad? I thought it was out of less importance, however I feel good that folks keep informing on unclear behaviors.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a tool such as http://seleniumhq.org/

> Selenium IDE is a Firefox add-on that
>   records clicks, typing, and other
>   actions to make a test, which you can
>   play back in the browser.

Comment: It would be nice to add this bit of info into your question. However I  still think Selenium (or similar) is your best bet for truly simulation users on a web site.

Comment: I can also recommend UserFly for that purpose, which is nearly a magic wand tool for tracking activities on the web. However it's a tracking tool that needs to be implemented.

Comment: I agree. Apologize for being unclear! But still. A tool like what you suggest is not what i'm out for. AS you say, it's a IDE. Require user interaction. I'm not out for tracking activites. The email at the end is just a simple way to tell me that i successed forcing the form with the httprespons/request console client.

Comment: userfly is not quite the same as selenium as it tracks users that come to your site after IT is live. Selenium can test a development site.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you are looking for a framework to unit test your application.

The best framework to test your web apps out there is [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) according to my knowledge.

Here is the [article](http://www.stevetrefethen.com/blog/AutomatedtestingofASPNETwebapplicationsusingSelenium.aspx) that gives you an idea on how to start out with this framework.
Hope this helps.